# Android layout space-filling problem

Tags: android, layout, truncate, space, fill

I'm having real difficulty coming up with a layout which works. I have a view which fills the width of the screen. It contains three sub-views:

1. Some text
2. A number in parentheses after the main text
3. A button

The button is right-aligned, and the text items are left-aligned one after the other, as shown:

```
| Some heading text (n)             [button]  |
```

The problem is controlling what happens when the text is too long. I want it like this, so that the number is always visible just to the right of the main text. The main text should be truncated if needed so the other two views remain visible.

```
| Some very very long headin... (n) [button]  |
```

The closest I've got which succesfully truncates the main text results in the (n) always being right-aligned next to the button even when the main text is short enough to fit. That's not what I want.

How would you approach this?

I'm not posting any of my current XML yet, lest it prejudice anyone's suggestions.

Comment: I've tried both RelativeLayout and LinearLayout. RelativeLayout seems best for the outer container, to fix the button to the right, and I've tried nesting the two text views inside either another RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ellipsize only a section in a TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228312/ellipsize-only-a-section-in-a-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there's any xml layout for that. My guess is that you will need to **extend `TextView`** and **measure the text length inside `onDraw(...)`**, adjusting the text accordingly through some iteration (i.e., removing one character at a time until the text fits the canvas)

I just found another question that is quite similar to yours: [Ellipsize only a section in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228312/ellipsize-only-a-section-in-a-textview) . No other answer than ellipsize in the middle.

---

**Another thoughts:**

I'm wondering if it would work to have **one textview with the main text** (**ellipsize left**, **wrap_content**) and **another with the number** in the parenthesis (**wrap_content**), **both inside an horizontal linear layout**. That layout would be **inside a relative layout** and **layout_toLeftOf** the button, which would be **wrap_content**, **layout_alignParentRight**.

Does it make any sense? I don't have Eclipse now to test it myself. Not sure if the (n) textview would be lost behind the button or not with a long text.

Alternatively (and less interesting), you can setup **one single relative layout** with the two textviews **all layout_toRightOf** and the button aligned to the right (**layout_alignParentRight**) and set the max witdth ot the first textview (**android:maxWidth**). *You would need to set up different layouts for different screens, though.*

---

## An example with a fixed max width that will work as required:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click me"
    android:id="@+id/bt1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />    
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="short text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="(n)"
    android:lines="1"
    android:id="@+id/n1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/t1"
    />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click me"
    android:id="@+id/bt2"
    android:layout_below="@id/bt1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />    
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="very long text that will not fit in any layout, regardless of the size of the screen"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:id="@+id/t2"
    android:layout_below="@id/bt1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:maxWidth="220dp"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="(n)"
    android:lines="1"
    android:id="@+id/n2"
    android:layout_below="@id/bt1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/t2"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Your nested layout idea didn't quite work: the number disappears behind the button.

Comment: The final outcome: I ended up using android:ellipsize="middle", as in the other question you found. It's not totally satisfactory but it's the best compromise I've been able to find.

Comment: @Graham back home I was playing with Eclipse a little bit. If you can afford using max widths (e.g. 200dp), then you can get the desired result. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Try a linearlayout, set the weight of the text view as 1,, and set ellipsis as `TruncateAt.MIDDLE`. Check this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="middle" android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is the ordering of the items as this is the order they are measured, in order to ensure your button and `(n)` text get enough space in the overall layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/middle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button"
    android:text="(n)"
    />

   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/middle"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:gravity="left"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:text="Some really long to text to make this flow over"
     android:lines="1"
     android:maxLines="1"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. This suffers from the problem I mentioned in the question: it's fine when the text is too long, but when the text is short then the middle view is fixed to the right (next to the button) when it should be immediately adjacent to the main TextView.