# Ellipsize string before last word in android

Tags: android, ellipse

I need to implement this functional:
I have some string.For example

> Found teddy bears 10

If this string can't fit the view, it should became

> Found teddy b...10

Also, if I haven't value of found items it's should be

> Found teddy bears

and

> Found teddy b...

`ellipses="middle"` is not suitable for me.

Found next answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12252144/1839853, but this code doesn't work for me.

Comment: this should probably be split in 2 textviews

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv.setText("Found teddy bears 10");
        doEllipse(tv,1);

public void doEllipse(final TextView tv, final int maxLine) {

        if (tv.getTag() == null) {
            tv.setTag(tv.getText());
        }
        ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                if (maxLine <= 0) {
                    int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
                    String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3) + "..."+tv.getText().subSequence(lineEndIndex - 3, lineEndIndex)+"";
                    tv.setText(text);

                } else if (tv.getLineCount() >= maxLine) {
                    int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(maxLine - 1);
                    String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3) + "..."+tv.getText().subSequence(lineEndIndex - 3, lineEndIndex)+"";
                    tv.setText(text);

                }
            }
        });

    }
```