# Android floating fixed width text effect

Tags: android, android-layout

I do not know how to name such effect but here is what I wan't to achieve. And I wonder if it's possible to do that just with xml layouts.

I have 2 text views. `Text_View_A` `Text_View_B`

`Text_View_A` has ellipsize enabled.

I want that `Text_View_B` would always be to the right of `Text_View_A`
[image]

but also so that `Text_View_A` would be to the left of `Text_View_B` and ellipsize would kick in if there is not enough room for it.
[image]

Is it possible to achieve that with just layouting? Or do I have to do manual calculations?

Comment: This post is poorly written, if you would like to be helped; revise.

Comment: found solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228312/ellipsize-only-a-section-in-a-textview

Answer (score 0):

You can use **relative layout** and set `Text_View_B`  to `parentRight true` and set `Text_View_A toLeft` of `Text_View_B.`

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Text_View_B"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Text_View_A"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Text_View_B" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Bit that will always make Text_View_B stick to the right of the screen, while I need it to stick to the Text_View_A.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout>
      <TextView android:id="@+id/textview_1" android:weight="7" />
      <TextView android:weight="3"/>
</LinearLayout>

textview_1.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
textview_1.setMaxWidth(textview_1.getMeasuredWidth());
```

try this.